# How to prove statements

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$m^2+mn+n^2$ is even $\iff$ $m$ and $n$ are both even

I have tried m and n both even $\Rightarrow$ $m^2+mn+n^2$ is even by:

$m=2p$
$n=2q$

$(2p)^2+2p*2q+(2q)^2$

$4p^2+4pq+4q^2$

$2(2p^2+2pq+2q^2)$

$2$ times an integer makes it even. I am unsure how to prove it the other way and whether my proof is even correct.

Thank you

Comment: Prove $\implies$ by contrapositive or contradiction.

Comment: HINT: Simply go backwards.

Answer (score 4):

There are three cases:none are even, one is even, or both are even:

If none is even then $m^2, mn$ and $n^2$ are all odd and the sum of three odds is odd.

if one is even then $mn$ is even an exactly one of $m^2$ and $n^2$ is even. therefore it is the sum of one odd and two evens which is odd.

if all are even then $m^2, mn$ and $n^2$ are even which makes the sum even.

Answer (score 2):

To prove $$m^2 + mn + n^2 \implies m, n \text{ are both even},$$

Prove: $$\lnot (m, n \text{ are both even}) \implies m^2 + mn + n^2 \;\text{is not even.}$$Assume that "It is **not the case** that $m, n$ are both even."

So there are three cases to consider.

- $m$ odd, $n$ odd.
- $m$ odd, $n$ even.
- $m$ even, $n$ odd.

Considering the first case and either of the second two cases suffices.

Comment: This needs a TU +1

Answer (score 0):

Write $m=2k_1+r_1$ and $n=2k_2+r_2,$ where $k_1,k_2,r_1,r_2$ are integers, and $r_1,r_2\in\{0,1\}$. From this, and the fact that $r_1^2=r_1$ and $r_2^2=r_2$ in either case, we see that $$\begin{align}m^2+mn+n^2 &= (2k_1+r_1)^2+(2k_1+r_1)(2k_2+r_2)+(2k_2+r_2)^2\\ &= 4k_1^2+4k_1r_1+r_1^2+4k_1k_2+2k_1r_2+2k_2r_1+r_1r_2+4k_2^2+4k_2r_2+r_2^2\\ &= 2(2k_1^2+2k_1r_1+2k_1k_2+k_1r_2+k_2r_1+2k_2^2+2k_2r_2)+r_1^2+r_1r_2+r_2^2\\ &= 2(2k_1^2+2k_1r_1+2k_1k_2+k_1r_2+k_2r_1+2k_2^2+2k_2r_2)+r_1+r_1r_2+r_2.\end{align}$$

It follows that $m^2+mn_n^2$ is even if and only if $r_1+r_1r_2+r_2$ is even. We need only show that this happens if and only if $r_1=r_2=0$. One direction of the inequality is immediate. For the other direction, if $r_1=1,$ then $r_1+r_1r_2+r_2=1+2r_2$ is odd. Likewise if $r_2=1.$ Thus, if $m$ or $n$ is odd, then $r_1=1$ or $r_2=1,$ and so $m^2+mn+n^2$ is odd. By contrapositive, if $m^2+mn+n^2$ is even, then both $m$ and $n$ are even.

---

This becomes simpler if you're familiar with modular arithmetic. The (rough) idea in this case is that we treat every multiple of $2$ like zero. This simplifies our task a great deal, for then $$\begin{align}m^2+mn+n^2 &= (2k_1+r_1)^2+(2k_1+r_1)(2k_2+r_2)+(2k_2+r_2)^2\\ &\equiv_2 (0+r_1)^2+(0+r_1)(0+r_2)+(0+r_2)^2\\ &= r_1^2+r_1r_2+r_2^2\\ &= r_1+r_1r_2+r_2,\end{align}$$ so again, the problem reduces to considering $r_1+r_1r_2+r_2,$ and in particular, showing that $m^2+mn+n^2\equiv_20$ if and only if $r_1,r_2=0.$ Once again, one direction of the implication is easy. For the other, if $r_1=1,$ then $m^2+mn+n^2\equiv_2r_1+r_1r_2+r_2=1+2r_2\equiv_21.$ Likewise if $r_2=1.$

Answer (score 0):

Noting: $$m^2+mn+n^2=(m+n)^2-mn$$

If it is even then both $mn$ and $(m+n)^2$ are even.

It means (m+n) is even so both m and n are even.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most obvious ways to do this is to observe that for expressions involving only addition, subtraction, and multiplication (like $m^2+mn+n^2$; subtraction is not even used here) one can always deduce its parity from the parities of all ingredients (here $m$ and $n$). The reason is you can do this for every basic addition, subtraction and multiplication used, working from smaller to larger subexpressions. Since that makes only $2\times2=4$ possibilities in all, it becomes a no-brainer: for all combinations of the parities of $m$ and $n$, compute the parity of $m^2+mn+n^2$. Only in case both $m$ and $n$ are even does the result become even, in the three other cases it becomes odd. This check is perfectly fine as a proof.

Of course one would prefer another method if there were a dozen or so different variables in the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo $2$ we have
$$m^2+mn+n^2\equiv m+ mn+n\equiv(m+1)(n+1)-1\ .$$
It follows that the left side is $\equiv0$ iff $(m+1)(n+1)\equiv1$, i.e., iff $m\equiv n\equiv0$.